# Is there any way to ignore local commit history when merging and pushing to remote?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

We want to have **per-developer branches** on git. In other words, developers would branch off of the "development" branch and create a local "feature" branch of their own to work on.

When they feel satisfied with their work, they can swap over to `devel`, make sure they have the latest files, and then merge in their "feature" branch and push the result to origin after dealing with any conflicts. 
However, there is a problem - this makes the commit history very messy.

If you do `git log --graph`, the "feature" branches don't show up, which is what we want. However, *every single commit that developer made* now shows up on the `devel` branch. That's ugly. If there's 10 developers and each one made 30 commits to their feature branch before they all got merged into devel, devel now shows a history of 180 commits for a total of 6 features. It would be nicer if the history just showed messages for the 6 merges into devel.

**Is there some way to avoid making the history "messy" and ignore the history of a local branch when merging?** Or is this just fighting git too much?

I realize this might sound odd, but they very much **dislike the idea of all those objects ending up on the remote repo**.

Comment: @RomainValeri That's fair. I just didn't want people to tear me apart for using git "wrong" if that's what they felt. I've edited the post appropriately.

Comment: Way better. Interesting question anyway, upvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If you do `git log`, the "feature" branches don't show up, which is what we want. However, every single commit that developer made now shows up on the devel branch.*

`git log`, by default, shows you a linear version of history that is simple and false. Git history is not linear. Branches really branch.

Instead of this...

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H [devel]
```

Your history really looks like this.

```
A ---------- E ----- H [devel]
 \          / \     /
  B - C - D    F - G
```

You can see this with `git log --graph` or a Git visualization tool like [Gitup](https://gitup.co/).

Each of those "feature bubbles" are the commits from each branch. Using the true history you can see what commits were developed as part of one feature. While this might seem "messy", this is important to understanding the code. Its especially useful along with `git blame`.

> *Is there some way to avoid making the history "messy" and ignore the history of a local branch when merging? Or is this just fighting git too much?*

My advice is to get used to it, and to learn how to navigate it. For example, `git log --merges` will only show the merge commits. A good Git visualization tool will help a lot.

The other is to encourage developers to clean up their branches before committing. If you have a lot of commits that are "typo fix" and "oops" and "broke the tests" these are of little value going forward. [They can use `git commit --amend` to change the previous commit, and `git rebase -i` "fixup" to merge existing commits together](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/git-interactive-rebase-squash-amend-rewriting-history). This ensures all commits are of some consequence.

If you really want to, you can do a "squash merge", `git merge --squash`. Rather than retaining the complete commit history this smashes all the changes and all the commit messages in the branch into one commit.

While this produces a "clean" history, it loses a lot of granular information about how the code was developed. If there are, for example, 30 commits in the branch and you do a `git blame` to understand some code you'll get the commit messages for all 30 commits with no way to know which one applies to the code.

What you see as "messy" is valuable insights into *why* the code was written the way it is. This is ***gold*** for anyone working with the code down the line. Once smashed together it can never be recovered.

Comment: There's some great info here. I should have clarified though, I meant even if you use ```git log --graph``` (which is what I was using), the "devel" branch would still be 180 commits long in this case, rather than 6. But git merge --squash may be exactly what we're looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

As  your team has observed, if you make a habit of merging first-draft work with all its initial errors and crappy organization and almost-good-enough experiments and the fixes, your history will be an unholy terror of a swamp.

Don't Do That.

Do the first-draft work in your local repo¹.  Then completely rewrite that first-draft history for publication, `git rebase -i` is the usual command recommended for this, but I've found a `git reset --soft` followed by `git add --patch`s is more convenient to create a reviewable history, one that's fit for public consumption. Then completely rework it as the feedback makes any infelicities apparent, and publish/merge the clean result.

The first-draft commit series that's local to the developer repo is of no more use to others than a readout of their editor undo-buffer history.  In fact, that's what a first-draft Git history essentially is: a project-wide editor undo buffer, with notes to help with next week's inevitable "what was I *thinking*?" questions.  Nobody else ever needs to see those. They're the notes on your desk, work product, destined for the trash can at birth.

---

<sup>¹ it's fine to have a swamp repo where developers can push their WIP stuff for visibility and collaboration, the important thing is to not treat WIP histories as anything but discardable notes no matter who has a copy.  How you administer them is very, very different from how you administer anything that's been pushed into production</sup>

Comment: I think I may have miscommunicated. The idea was that each developer would continue working locally until they felt their "feature" branch was very well and truly done. The issue is that, to get to that point, they may make dozens or several dozen completely local commits. Even if those are only local, all of that history shows up in the log when it is eventually merged in.

Comment: No, I think I buried the lede, reread my last paragraph while I figure out how to make the post clearer.  The point is, in no other field does published work include the first-draft versions and all the corrections.  There is nothing sacred about your average first-draft commit, anything unmerged can and should be treated as a throwaway.

Comment: May be you should make more clear that `git rebase -i` offers all required means to clean up the history, including reordering commits and squashing several commits into one. I think that is what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

> *Is there some way to avoid making the history "messy" and ignore the history of a local branch when merging? Or is this just fighting git too much?*

Absolutely. Simply, don't merge anything. Have a public repo where you individually cherry-pick the commits. One way to do this is via a review system like Gerrit.

Cherry-picking will ensure you have clean, linear history without the merge mess.

However, it's important to get the individual changes: i.e. if 15 commits were required to develop a feature, then 15 commits should be recorded. It's important for various reasons. One is that multiple smaller commits make it easier to find and isolate bugs with `git bisect`. If a small commit which changes a single line is implicated as the cause of a regression, that is easier to figure out than if a commit with three hundred changes is implicated as that same regression.

What should be encouraged is that developers clean up their feature branches before merging. For instance, don't have commits which just fix trivial compiler errors ("Forgot a semicolon in `parse_descriptor`, oops!").  Or commits that "clean up" code that was only made messy in by that same feature development in the first place.
Commits "off topic" to the feature branch should also be discouraged.

A good rule to adopt is that every commit should build; no commit should break anything such that it requires a subsequent commit. Such commits should be squashed together.

Everyone should understand how to use `git`'s interactive rebase to re-order, squash and correct commits.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible to only commit working branches. Maybe you meant "merge to master" where I agree: only commit working code (passes all tests at least). One of the best ways to screw your other team members is putting broken code into something they will end up merging. You end up with a tangled mess, especially if the broken code doesn't immediately reveal its problem and more commits get piled on top of it, where you then need to use git-bisect to find which commit broke the build, and thus you need an unsquashed history to be able to find the exact commit that is causing the problem.

But there are all sorts of reasons to commit unfinished work in a separate branch.

1. Saving your current workspace before you try something new that might not work out and you may need to easily restore your workspace.
2. You need to stop using one computer and pick up work on another, like going home from work.
3. You may have done some great unfinished work on a feature, that ends up not being used but the utility functions you wrote to support the new feature will probably be useful at a later date. By parking it in a branch, you get around the urge to keep "all that work you did" in the main product.

The problem with squashing is, every once in a while you encounter a really nasty bug and you need to do a git bisect (binary search of commits) to discover the exact commit that caused the bug. Git has become a code organizer, not a version control system due to all this mania about squashing and having clean commits. You can always do

```
git log --simplify-by_decoration
```

if you only want to see important or primary commits.

You can have the best of both worlds by creating a separate squashed branch before you merge to master, but leave the old unsquashed one intact. Or vice versa, create an unsquashed branch, and squash the original one before merging to master.

Then you have a way to see individual commits if you need to, but don't mess up your master branch.